# RegEx to match part of string that may or may not be present

Tags: regex

I have strings that are in the format:

```
X=Foo, Y=Bar, Z=Qux
```

However, sometimes only the `X=...Y=...` parts are there, not the `Z=...` part, e.g:

```
X=Foo, Y=Bar
```

And also can capture commas *within* values, like:

```
X=Foo, bar, Y=Bar, Z=Qux
```

How can I write a regex to capture Foo, Bar, and Qux (just placeholders for this example) if present?

I've come up with this so far:

```
X=(.*), Y=(.*)           # Works when Z is not present
X=(.*), Y=(.*), Z=(.*)   # Works when Z is present
```

But I'm having trouble writing a single regex to match both cases. I also tried something like this:

```
X=(.*), Y=(.*)(, Z=(.*))?
```

I thought that by grouping the `,Z=(.*)` in its own group followed by a `?` it would treat the whole group as optional, but it still seems to group the `Z=` as part of the captured part from the `Y=`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were very close - you're capturing it, but in group *4*, due to the new group you introduced to make the last part optional.

Change the introduced group to a *non-capturing* group:

```
X=(.*?), Y=(.*?)(?:, Z=(.*))?$
```

I also fixed your capture to *reluctant* (instead of `.*`, which is *greedy* and consumes the entire rest of input).

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/yeS8xKFjtr).

Comment: I don't want to use `\w` because the values may contain other characters, including commas. Are you able to revise your answer?

Comment: sure. is a comma-then-space a suitable separator then?

Comment: Hmm, I can't be certain right now. Is it possible to write a regex that could capture, for example, both: `X=foo, bar, Y=baz, Z=qux` (catpure `foo, bar`, `baz`, and `qux`) and `X=foo, Y=bar` (capture `foo` and `bar`) ?

Comment: @Joseph I have fixed the regex to match "anything"