# preg_match regex to match part of a string that may or may not be present

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to parse some text reports into structured data. Typical lines are

```
 Cat. No.: 1      Location: Bottles, boxes etc
 Cat. No.: 25      Location: Woods size B      EBN: 63.1868
 Cat. No.: 24      Location: Woods size B      EBN: 12.1980.221
 Cat. No.: 20      Location: Woods size B      EBN: 4.1973
 Cat. No.: 19      Location: Woods size B
```

The first two values are always present, the last is optional.

`/Cat\. No\.: (\d+)      Location: (.+)(?:      EBN: ([\d\.]+))/`

works for lines with all three values but my instinct is that I need to add a ? to the end to make the last part optional i.e.

`/Cat\. No\.: (\d+)      Location: (.+)(?:      EBN: ([\d\.]+))/?`

I am then finding that capture group 2 is matching everything after 'Location: ' so for e.g. line 2 it becomes 'Woods size B      EBN: 63.1868'

Have saved this at https://regex101.com/r/gd0pKH/1 and would be grateful for any advice. [RegEx to match part of string that may or may not be present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733751/regex-to-match-part-of-string-that-may-or-may-not-be-present) appears to be the same question and has the same answer I came up with, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working for me!

Comment: Can the location contain a comma? Do you need to match the first line? You may add anchors on both sides and replace that `.+` with `.+?`, `^Cat\. No\.: (\d+)      Location: (.+?)(?:      EBN: ([\d\.]+))?$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mdz9Om/1).

Comment: You call this "structured data," is it tab separated? It would probably be easier to handle it with `str_getcsv()` if so

Comment: Also your second regex has the question mark outside the slash delimiters.

Comment: @wiktor+tribizew thanks, this appears to be the solution
@miken32 I considered using explode() (though str_getcsv looks to be even better!) but regex felt more compact. Do you know which one would perform best?  As to the syntax issue - my typing mistake in the posting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fix your regex with the following steps:

1. The second matching group (`(.+)`) should be ungready, or it would match everything till the end of the line: `(.+?)`
2. You should add an anchor to the end of the line `$`, otherwise the regex would stop with the first matching expression - which is obviously the shorter version and in this case, your third matching group would be empty.

Alltogether, you get this:

```
Cat\. No\.: (\d+)      Location: (.+?)(?:      EBN: ([\d\.]+))?$
```

In addition, you could thin about, using `\s+`, instead of the six spaces, which makes the expression more flexible.

```
Cat\. No\.: (\d+)\s+Location: (.+?)(?:\s+EBN: ([\d\.]+))?$
```

Comment: Thanks for this, and the detailed explanation. Makes total sense and works a treat

Answer (score 1):

You can have the `Location` value repeat lazily, and then use positive lookahead for either two spaces in a row (for a line with `EBN`), or the end of the line (for a line without `EBN`):

```
Cat\. No\.: (\d+)      Location: (.+?)(?=  |$)(?:      EBN: ([\d\.]+))?
```

https://regex101.com/r/gd0pKH/2

Comment: Thanks, I would have been happy to mark this as the accepted answer but @Phiipp had just got here first with the same solution!